# How can install Matplotlib with PyCharm without use terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, installation, data-science

I can't install `matplotlib` or other lib with terminal, is there any way to install `matplotlib` with `PyCharm` without using terminal?

Comment: Any specific reasons why you can't install it through the terminal ? Just curious as it would be a lot easier that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you just type 'import matplotlib' as normal Pycharm will detect that it isn't installed and offer to install it from the IDE if you hover over the text.